# CSS underlining

Tags: html, css, underline

To underline text in CSS we can do:

```
h3 {text-decoration:underline;}
```

However this only underlines the text enclosed in h3 tag.  What if want the underline to go across the page?

Thanks

Comment: what you mean with **across the page**? something like applying that style to the body tag or similar?

Comment: Yes, please clarify your question.

Comment: Or you can add markup to this <u>asdasdasd</u>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/f5ptL/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Then you wouldn't have an underline, you'd have a border on the element.

```
border-bottom: 1px red solid;
```

Comment: I think you mean border-bottom.

Comment: I did. Suddenly I'm feeling the need for the day to end. :)

Comment: Yes, you've already hit the 200k mark, so you ought to wind down ;) (In all seriousness, congrats on making it!)

Answer (score 5):

You could try using a border:

```
h3 { border-bottom: 1px solid }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your element lies directly under the body tag you can use:

```
h3 {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

And the line will span across the entire page, or whatever element it is within...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the horizontal rule (hr) tag? This can also be stylized however you'd like.

---